# Java Global File Array Looses Subscripts After Method

Tags: java

I am working in a Java program where I want to be able to use a FileArray's subscripts after it exits the method in which the FileArray gains it's subscript values. I have declared the FileArray in a public scope in it's class, however, once the FileArray exits the method in which it's subscript values are given, the FileArray becomes null and cannot be used to represent the values that it had gained in it's previous method. How can I get this FileArray to keep it's subscripts persistent throughout the whole class. Any help would be very much appreciated. By the way, the name of the FileArray is "listOfFiles".

```
package prototype_1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileExtensionReader {

// Current folder/directory-path used for testing:
// C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\grupeeTestFolder

private Scanner sc; // Declare Scanner Object
private String bulkFolderPath; // Declare String representing path to folder
                                // that contains files
private File[] listOfFiles;

public void readFiles() { // Reads and saves filenames in Array
    System.out.println("Please enter folder/directory filepath"); // Prompt
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // enter
                                                                    // Folder/Directory
                                                                    // path
    sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Create Scanner Object
    bulkFolderPath = sc.nextLine(); // String representing folder/directory
                                    // path to folder/directory containing
                                    // files
    File folder_directory = new File(bulkFolderPath); // File Object of bulk
                                                        // folder
    File[] listOfFiles = folder_directory.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File::: " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("If this prints, it means 'listOfFiles' FileArray"
            + " is consistent within this method, and the number printed " + "represents the number of "
            + "files found" + "\n" + "by the program. " + "Number: " + listOfFiles.length + "     "
            + listOfFiles[0]);
}

public void groupFilenames() {
    System.out.println("Number again: " + listOfFiles);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileExtensionReader FER1 = new FileExtensionReader();
    FER1.readFiles();
    FER1.groupFilenames();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a [*variable shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) in `readFiles` with

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder_directory.listFiles();
```

change it to something like

```
listOfFiles = folder_directory.listFiles();
```

Comment: Any good IDE should have warned about this too. Use an IDE, e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA, BlueJ, ..., and you'll save lots of time over time.

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** *distinct* variables named `listOfFiles`.  When you write something like

```
SomeType variable = something;
```

this declares a new variable.  If you do this twice, it might be illegal.  But if it's legal, as it is in your code, then you're declaring two different variables.  One is local to the `readFile` method, and one is an instance variable.  If you assign the local variable a value, it will have no impact on the instance variable, since it's a totally different variable with the same name.

If you want to assign your instance variable, then just say

```
variable = something;
```

i.e.

```
listOfFiles = folder_directory.listFiles();
```

without the type.